# XCTest can't find the test bundle

Tags: xcode, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I am trying to write XCUItests for an iOS app that is build using Appcelerator-Alloy. I opened the xcodeproject from the build folder, added a UI test bundle and then a UI test class (it has an autogenerated test method). I followed this tutorial:

https://blog.novoda.com/getting-started-with-xcuitest-framework-for-testing-ios-apps/

When I try to run the tests, they fail with these logs:

> 2018-08-08 11:52:00.177912-0400 YTB_UITests-Runner[14519:443448] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No test bundle found at file:///Users/nvishnoi/ytb/build/iphone/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YTB_UITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/YTB_UITests.xctest'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010379f1e6 **exceptionPreprocess + 294
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102e34031 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001037a4472 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
>       3   Foundation                          0x000000010290d64f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 165
>       4   XCTest                              0x0000000102720aea _XCTestMain + 761
>       5   YTB_UITests-Runner                  0x00000001023c749f _XCTRunnerRunTests + 57
>       6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103741b0c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
>       7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001037262db __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 331
>       8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103725a84 __CFRunLoopRun + 1284
>       9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010372530b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
>       10  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000104906a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000105b75057 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       12  YTB_UITests-Runner                  0x00000001023c76dc main + 42
>       13  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108047955 start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb) .

I have checked out documentation at developer.apple.com as well and I don't see anything wrong in my test class.